# How to securely sign requests with aws credentials?

Tags: php, python, security, amazon-web-services, boto

I am not entirely sure if this is the question I should be asking so feel free to submit edits.

I am developing a desktop app I plan to distribute and use amazon Polly to read text the user enters.  I am having trouble understanding how to securely allow users to access the service under our program without exposing the access key.

I saw in a previous example that I should create a request to use the resource, have the access and secret access key in a server and it sign the request.  Then send it back to the user on the desktop application.

If this is correct could someone explain and give me a simple example of how to accomplish this in python? Thank you. :)

Here is what I have so far that I would like to be on the code clients download:

```
from boto3 import  client
import boto3
import StringIO
from contextlib import closing

polly = boto3.client(
    'polly',
    region_name='us-east-1',
    aws_access_key_id='I_want_to_protect_this',
    aws_secret_access_key='I_also_want_to_protect_this'
)

response = polly.synthesize_speech(
    Text="Good Morning. My Name is Rajesh. I am Testing Polly AWS Service For Voice Application.",
    OutputFormat="mp3",
    VoiceId="Raveena")

print(response)

if "AudioStream" in response:
    with closing(response["AudioStream"]) as stream:
        data = stream.read()
        fo = open("pollytest.mp3", "w+")
        fo.write( data )
        fo.close()
```

Comment: You could try using Cognito to avoid having to alias requests.

Comment: Are you saying that you want your customers to be able to call AWS directly, using credentials from your AWS account? Do you realise that you would have no ability to restrict how many times they called it, which could cause you extra expense? Or do you wish them to make a request to Polly *via your application* rather than directly?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I didn't know there was a difference.  I would actually only like my desktop application to be able to call requests for specific things for the user.  I.E. user opens the app and it gives them a custom greeting "Good morning David, I have found some resources for you..."  However, again the challenge is this is a downloadable desktop app

Comment: @JordonPhillips I believe Cognito is only for mobile apps like iPhone, am I wrong?

Comment: @Davidhall while Cognito heavily features mobile support, you should be able to use it anywhere you can use one of the SDKs.

Comment: @JordonPhillips Okay, awesome! I'll continue to try and learn and understand more about Cognito.  However, if you know of a way to do a simple example with Cognito in Python, I'm sure it could benefit a lot of people and myself!:) Thank you.

Comment: @JordonPhillips Cognito, mixed with lambda and RDS appears to be exactly what I need!  Users signup through a boto3 python client app and have to confirm via email, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct approach for providing people with access to AWS services and resources stored on AWS is to take a client/server approach.

The **client** in your case is a Desktop application, but it could equally be a mobile app or a web app. The client is basically *untrusted* and should not be given any credentials for accessing AWS.

The **server** is an application running somewhere (typically on Amazon EC2 or AWS Lambda) that receives requests from the client, applies business logic (eg verifying the user's identity and determining what actions they are permitted to take) and calls AWS services.

Then there are two approaches to making calls to AWS:

- The **server** can make all the calls to AWS (using credentials that are available only to the server) and pass back results to the client. This isolates the client from AWS and allows you to insert custom business logic within the server. (eg When you use Netflix, your TV doesn't call AWS directly.) Or...
- The **server** can verify the identity of the client (eg the user logs into the client app, which sends the login details to server) by consulting a database of authorized application users, generate **temporary AWS credentials**, pass them back to the client and then the client can call AWS directly. (eg Many mobile apps do this to talk with Amazon S3.)

The **temporary AWS credentials** can be generated by the server by calling the [AWS Security Token Service](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html) and specifying the permissions and duration sought. STS will then return a set of time-limited credentials that have the desired permissions. The client application can use these credentials to call AWS services (eg Amazon Polly as per your code sample).

This way, no credentials are stored in the client code and the server controls whether the client is permitted to access AWS, which API calls can be used and how long the access should be granted.

Comment: Could you please explain more on how to use aws lambda from a desktop application in python?  From what I've been looking into it seems I need to add credentials to be able to call the lambda function.  I feel this is partly because I am confused about how all these pieces should be interacting.  Thank you for the great answer.

Comment: Your desktop app should ask the server for some credentials; the server confirms whether it is allowed to use your account and, if so, creates temporary credentials by calling STS and passes them back to the desktop app. The desktop app can then call AWS services. But... why do you want your desktop app to call Lambda? It is normally triggered in response to an event or a request.

Comment: okay, awesome! Thanks.  I wanted it to call lambda because I thought it was one of the ways of giving full access to the server.  i.e.  The client calls the lambda that has the credentials on it.  The lambda creates an mp3 with Polly and returns the mp3 file.  However,  I don't think this is possible without giving credentials to the client.

Comment: That is certainly a good way of doing things -- you could create a Lambda function that calls Polly using its own credentials. You can then expose the Lambda function to the world via the AWS API Gateway service. Then, your desktop application simply calls the API, Lambda does the work and sends back the result. This is a very clean way of doing client/server interactions.